# Object copied with python API have no users although it is used

Tags: python, node-editor

I have a material created with `ShaderNodeCustomGroup` and when I try to copy, I am having an issue with the internal node_tree not being correctly copied.

In my `ShaderNodeCustomGroup` I have implemented the copy(node) function.

```
    def copy(self, node):
        print("Before")
        print("self.node_tree.users {}, ({})".format(self.node_tree.users, self.node_tree))
        print("node.node_tree.users {}, ({})".format(node.node_tree.users, node.node_tree))

        copy = node.node_tree.copy()
        print("Intermediate")
        print("copy.users {}, (){})".format(copy.users, copy))
        print("self.node_tree.users {}, ({})".format(self.node_tree.users, self.node_tree))
        print("node.node_tree.users {}, ({})".format(node.node_tree.users, node.node_tree))
        self.node_tree = copy
        self.wrapped.node_tree = self.wrapped.node_tree.copy()

        print("After")
        print("self.node_tree.users {}, ({})".format(self.node_tree.users, self.node_tree))
        print("node.node_tree.users {}, ({})".format(node.node_tree.users, node.node_tree))
```

The output of this is the following:

```
Before
self.node_tree.users 1, (<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree(".IroDiffuse_wrapper") at 0x7f3ed206d808>)
node.node_tree.users 1, (<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree(".IroDiffuse_wrapper") at 0x7f3ed206d808>)
Intermediate
copy.users 0, ()<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree(".IroDiffuse_wrapper.001") at 0x7f3ed2d54c08>)
self.node_tree.users 1, (<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree(".IroDiffuse_wrapper") at 0x7f3ed206d808>)
node.node_tree.users 1, (<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree(".IroDiffuse_wrapper") at 0x7f3ed206d808>)
After
self.node_tree.users 1, (<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree(".IroDiffuse_wrapper.001") at 0x7f3ed2d54c08>)
node.node_tree.users 0, (<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree(".IroDiffuse_wrapper") at 0x7f3ed206d808>)
```

Initially I have `self` and `node` sharing the same `node_tree`, but the `node_tree` itself only has 1 user, which is weird.

Then, I ciopy the `node_tree`, which gives me an unused `node_tree` with different address. Makes sense. Still, the original `node_tree` is only used by one user, which seems incorrect.

Finally, I assign the copied `node_tree` to `self`. This makes `self.node_tree` to have one user, but `node.node_tree` to have no users.

If I now save and reopen the file, one of the materials if broken. I believes that since `node.node_tree.users` is 0, it has been deleted by blender.

What is wrong with this?

I edit the qustion to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Given the following code, assign a test material to the default cube. Duplicate the cube and make the material unique. Save, exit, start blender again and open the file. One of the cubes is black.

````
import bpy
from bpy.types import ShaderNodeCustomGroup
from bpy.props import FloatProperty, FloatVectorProperty

class MinimalTestMaterial(ShaderNodeCustomGroup):

    bl_name='TestMaterial'
    bl_label='TestMaterial'
    label = 'Test material'

    def init(self, context):
        self.width = 250 # make it large

        self.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.new('TestMaterial', 'ShaderNodeTree')
        rgb = self.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeRGB")

        group_outputs = self.node_tree.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
        out = self.node_tree.outputs.new("out", "out")

        self.node_tree.links.new(rgb.outputs[0], group_outputs.inputs[0])

    def copy(self, node):
        self.node_tree = node.node_tree.copy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    from nodeitems_utils import NodeItem, register_node_categories, unregister_node_categories
    from nodeitems_builtins import ShaderNodeCategory
    
    bpy.utils.register_class(MinimalTestMaterial)
    newcatlist = [ShaderNodeCategory("SH_NEW_CUSTOM", "Test", items=[NodeItem(MinimalTestMaterial.__name__)])]
    register_node_categories("TEST_NODES", newcatlist)
```
````

Comment: This's just my two cents.   `.users` is not updated.   You might need to call some update (recalculate) function.    I encountered such issue about `Driver` once.

Comment: Ill check that. But its strange, when copying other stuff, it just works

Comment: I have tested adding node.update() and self.update() in the coopy function, but still doesn't work. To me it looks like a blender bug...

Comment: Since there are no answers, I will push my luck : try `.update_tag()`?